# JavaScript: Download file, modify and auto-upload

Tags: javascript

I want to allow the following process for a single page web-app:

1. User downloads a file (e.g. Word file) from the web app
2. User modifies the file locally
3. User re-uploads the changes to the web app

Is there a standard (or semi-standard) way in modern browsers (mainly Chrome, Firefox, Edge Chromium) to somehow automate the third step? The downloading part is of course simple in principle.

But can a browser "watch" a file that it has downloaded for changes and auto-upload the files? If this is not possible: Can the browser keep a "reference" to the downloaded file and pre-select the downloaded file so the user only has to press some upload button?

Editing with a JavaScript-based editor is not really an option as the user needs to be able to edit multiple different file formats (Office documents, PDFs, ...)

Comment: this article might help: https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit/

Comment: Thanks @chiliNUT. As far as I can see, this is only implemented in Chrome (and Edge Chromium) and won't be implemented in other browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem
Is there a different way to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: Probably not, outside of nodejs, for security reasons I dont think its advised to let js have access to the file system, tbh I was surprised by that article I found that it was even possible in a browser.

Comment: I fear you are right. According to this page: https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/Filesystem, there seem to be some open issues, and it would only work from a browser extension. Given the browsers sandboxing and security constraint, I already thought as much. Still, it would be nice to somehow have this possibility.